# How to only match folder up to a slash?

Tags: regex, mod-rewrite, regex-greedy

I am trying to match a folder, let's say 'b' in /a/b/c.jpg
When I use (.*) in my Rewriterule it is greedy and includes anything before and including the 'b' folder. How do I match 'b' only up to the slash where 'b' could be any character? Is there a rule that essentially looks at anything up to the first slash to the left? Thanks! I tried starting the rewriterule with a slash, but that doesn't work.

Comment: Generally, you have two options in this scenario. Most regex variants have a "reluctant" Kleene closure, usually denoted as `*?`, so you can often use that. In regex variants that lack reluctant operators, you can use a character class that omits the character you want to stop on, such as `[^/]*`.

Comment: You need to match whst is before and capture the last folder. Something like `.*/([^/]+)/[^/]*$`. The value will be in `$1`.

Comment: @anubhava I should have specified that there might be other sub-folders in front of 'a'

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks, that looks promising...I'll try that tonight.

Comment: @Welbog Thanks! I'll try that.

Comment: @anubhava agreed! I try to do a better job next time.

Comment: Got it to work using: Rewriterule ([^/]*)(\/\d+)?\/(\w+)\.jpg folder/folder/$1/$3.jpg [NC]

Answer (score 0):

To get `c/d.jpg` out of `a/b/c/d.jpg`

```
(\w+\/\w+\.\w+)
```

try it here: **[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/cU5lC2/542)**

```js
var reg = /(\w+\/\w+\.\w+)/;
var path = "a/b/c/d.jpg";

//document.write(reg.exec(path)[0]);

$("select").change(function(){
  $("input").val(reg.exec(this.value)[0]);
})
```

```css
select {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option value="/a/b/c/d.jpg">/a/b/c/d.jpg</option>
  <option value="x/y/a/folder/d.jpg">x/y/a/folder/d.jpg</option>
  <option value="g/a/b_test/d.jpg">g/a/b_test/d.jpg</option>
  <option value="h/i/j/a/Folder_01/d.jpg">h/i/j/a/Folder_01/d.jpg</option>
</select>
match <input type="text"></input>
```

Comment: Yes, but I only want c/d.jpg out of a/b/c/d.jpg hence why I'm looking for a non-greedy way to do this.